# AutocompleteTextView dismissDropDown() not working

Tags: java, android, dropdown, autocompletetextview, dismiss

I have an autocomplete textview that fires a HTTP request when text changes, to search in a remote database. The problem is when I click an item of the dropdown the TextWatcher detects it as a text change, so the dropdown never closes, even using dismissDropdown() method inside setOnItemClickListener. If I dont use the showDropdown() method, the dropdown closes correctly after clicking an item, but it has a weird behavior, in example: if result has 8 items it only shows 2 or never show them.

```
autocompleteDeposito.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           @Override
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               // No se necesita implementar
           }

           @Override
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               String nombreDeposito = charSequence.toString().trim();

               String url = "http://MY_SERVER_IP/buscarDeposito.php";
               StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(String response) {
                       try {
                           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                           boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

                           if (success) {
                               JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                               ArrayList<Deposito> depositoList = new ArrayList<>();

                               for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                                   JSONObject empleado = data.getJSONObject(i);

                                   String idDeposito = empleado.getString("id");
                                   String nombreDeposito = empleado.getString("nombre");
                                   Deposito dep = new Deposito(nombreDeposito, idDeposito);

                                   depositoList.add(dep);
                               }

                               AutoCompleteTextView autocompleteDeposito = findViewById(R.id.autocompleteDeposito);

                               // Configura un adaptador para el AutoCompleteTextView con los nombres de los empleados
                               ArrayAdapter<Deposito> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                                       RegistroActivity.this,
                                       android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                                       depositoList);

                               autocompleteDeposito.setThreshold(2);
                               autocompleteDeposito.setAdapter(adapter);
                               autocompleteDeposito.showDropDown();

                               autocompleteDeposito.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
                                   Deposito depositoSeleccionado = (Deposito) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                   depositoSeleccionadoId = depositoSeleccionado.getId();
                                   autocompleteDeposito.dismissDropDown();
                               });

                           } else {
                               Toast.makeText(RegistroActivity.this, "No se encontró el empleado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                           Toast.makeText(RegistroActivity.this, "Error al procesar respuesta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                   }
               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       // Errores de la solicitud
                   }
               }) {
                   @Override
                   protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                       // Parámetros POST
                       Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                       params.put("nombre_deposito", nombreDeposito);
                       return params;
                   }
               };

               RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
               requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

           }

           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
               // No se necesita implementar
           }
       });
```

XML:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autocompleteDeposito"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
    android:hint="@string/deposito_autocomplete"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solved by adding the next condition (not the best but the simplest).**

This way if depositoSeleccionadoNombre (selected item) and paramDeposito (search parameter) are equal, it means the user has already selected an option so the dropdown should not be shown:

```
// Declare depositoSeleccionadoNombre before protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
String depositoSeleccionadoNombre = "";

autocompleteDeposito.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence sec, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence sec, int start, int before, int count) {
        String paramBusqueda = sec.toString().trim();

        if (paramBusqueda.length() > 1) {
            buscarDeposito(paramBusqueda);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable sec) {

    }
});

private void buscarDeposito(String paramDeposito) {
    // Rest of the code...

    if (!depositoSeleccionadoNombre.equals(paramDeposito)) {
        autocompleteDeposito.showDropDown();
    }

    autocompleteDeposito.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
        Deposito depositoSeleccionado = (Deposito) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        depositoSeleccionadoId = depositoSeleccionado.getId();
        depositoSeleccionadoNombre = depositoSeleccionado.getNombre();
    });
}
```